# Sorting large arrays of big numeric stings

Tags: python

I was solving [bigSorting() problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/big-sorting/problem) from hackerrank:

> Consider an array of numeric strings where each string is a positive number with anywhere from `1` to `10^6` digits. Sort the array's elements in non-decreasing, or ascending order of their integer values and return the sorted array.

I know it works as follows:

```
def bigSorting(unsorted):
    return sorted(unsorted, key=int)
```

But I didnt guess this approach earlier. Initially I tried below:

```
def bigSorting(unsorted):
    int_unsorted = [int(i) for i in unsorted]
    int_sorted = sorted(int_unsorted)
    return [str(i) for i in int_sorted]
```

However, for some of the test cases, it was showing time limit exceeded. Why is it so?

PS: I dont know exactly what those test cases were as hacker rank does not reveal all test cases.

**Update**

My code is following three steps:

1. `str` to `int` conversion
2. Sorting
3. `int` to `str` convertsion

Why I felt that my code in OP should also run is that its also O(n log n). But seems that mere same time complexity is not enough here? But then I wanted to know which conversion is avoided by `sorted(unsorted, key=int)`?

**Q1.** The third one, `int` to `str` conversion?

**Q2.** If Yes is the answer to Q1, then is it the only reason why my code doesnt work and onliner-`sorted`-solution works? That is, is there anything else that my code is doing extra above onliner-`sorted`-solution?

**Q3.** Also wont onliner-`sorted`-solution do `str` to `int` conversion multiple times for the same number during sorting? That is, everytime it has to compare a specific number, does it have to convert it from `str` to `int`? Or `sorted` is implemented in such a way that it has to convert each element from `str` to `int` only once?

Comment: There are three steps involved in your approach - that's not too surprising.  Especially the cases may have huge list of strings

Comment: string  to integer conversion and then integer to string conversion plus O(NlogN) sorting, how are not supprised with TLE?

Comment: @sahasrara62 Especially the number of strings is *not* a problem there :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy talking about from this `["12345", ...] --> [12345,...]`, then do sort (NlogN) and then `[12345,...] --> ["12345", ...]` . not the number of values/string/element inside the list

Comment: @sahasrara62 Oops, I accidentally replied to the wrong person. I meant to reply to Daniel, who focused on exactly the one part that isn't a problem.

Comment: Why I felt that my code in OP should also run is that its also O(n log n). But seems that mere same time complexity is not enough here? Which conversion is avoided by `sorted(unsorted, key=int)`? Third one right? That is `sorted(unsorted, key=int)` doesnt need to do int to str conversion right? Also wont it do str to int conversion multiple times for the same number?

Comment: Sorry guys for super late update, I have updated the OP detailing above comment. Can you please check?

Answer (score 2):

Here you are converting list of numerical string to list of integer and vice a versa.

for each conversion of string to integer ie `'123456'` to `123456` time is consumed and for every 10x in strig size conversion is increased by 100x time . proofed by @kellybundy in his [post](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P60oP1ehJDM3NbNEITO3IL@oBMrj4iooyswr0YDwNNRBbCVLJS1DAy0tU011HYW80tyk1CJbQ01NPCrNUFX@/w8A)

adding code and run time if in case link disappear

```
from timeit import timeit

print(timeit('int("9"*10**5)', number=1))
print(timeit('int("9"*10**6)', number=1))
```

has run time

```
0.0568113109911792
5.422084125995752
```

so we can say time complexity of your conversion (string to integer)is O(n*n*m), where n is size of string, m is size of list.

This is where your code is taking time (conversion 2 time apart from sorting).

what you can do apart from orignal solution (`sorted(unsorted, key = int)` use python sorting of  string numerical, where it sort them   in lexical order ie `0,1,2,3,4`

```
def bigSorting(unsorted):
    return sorted(unsorted, key= lambda x:(len(x), x))
```

here code doesn't need to convert the element and then sort, but just sort only. so it will take NlogN time

Now a much much faster solution by @kellybundy (he should add this as solution of his own )

```
def bigSorting(unsorted):
    return sorted(unsorted, key= lambda x:int(x, 16))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246509/discussion-on-answer-by-sahasrara62-sorting-large-arrays-of-big-numeric-stings).

Answer (score 1):

In your code you:

1. Make a new `list` of `ints` converting `str -> int`.
2. Make a new sorted `list` of those `ints`.
3. Make *another* new `list` of `str`, converting `int --> str`.

That's three completely new (possibly massive) lists with multiple conversions.

Using the `key=int` sorting argument performs the necessary conversions internally during the sort process itself, which means there is never the costly conversion from `int -> str`.

We can supply Hacker Rank with just this code, and it passes all tests:

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(input())

    result = sorted((input() for _ in range(n)), key=int)

    fptr.write('\n'.join(result))
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Still not 'optimal' perhaps, but from reading through the comments, this does seem to be an expected option. Those performing bucket/merge sorts didn't see much performance gains.

Comment: Why I felt that my code in OP should also run is that its also O(n log n). But seems that mere same time complexity is not enough here? Which conversion is avoided by `sorted(unsorted, key=int)`? Third one right? That is `sorted(unsorted, key=int)` doesnt need to do int to str conversion right? Also wont it do str to int conversion multiple times for the same number?

Comment: Sorry guys for super late update, I have updated the OP detailing above comment. Can you please check?